What do you call a VPN that changes your public IP Address versus a VPN that doesn't change your public IP address?
What do you call a VPN (Virtual Private Network) that changes your public IP Address (e.g. using GlobalProtect VPN) versus a VPN that doesn't change your public IP address (e.g. using OpenVPN to access AWS resources in private VPN)?
What's the correct terminology for this?

so my guess is your openVPN client is configured for "split tunneling", whereas your PAGP client is configured to use a gateway on the remote network. Note that both these clients can be configured to work in the opposite mode you describe. Some clients like Wireguard, leave it to the system administrators to configure system routing to achieve either goal. the closest things i can come up with to answer your question is that the AWS connection is a point-to-site connection, and the other example is either point-to-site with remote gateway, or a point-to-world connection.

an additional note: both the VPNs you describe are "enterprisy" and seem to involve connecting to a specific network. if you are asking what a VPN designed entirely to grant access to the Internet like Nord or whatever, I would refer to that as a 'commercial privacy VPN service'. finally, all these "types" of connections are basically the same; the difference is how IP routing is configured.
